# string to Ivalue conversion

Tags: javascript, json

I need to assign a variable the following:

```
ref => { this.marker = ref}
```

This is happening in a loop and i need `this.marker` to be named like `this.marker + i`, so i can set and access `this.marker1`, `this.marker2` etc..

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Hey just off hand, is this for a course?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to index into the object by string:

```
this['marker' + i] = ref
```

In Javascript, `a.b` and `a['b']` are the same, except that in the latter, `'b'` can be replaced with any expression that results in a string (or indeed any value that Javascript is willing to treat as a string, which is anything at all).

That said, you might be better off with an array depending on your use case.

Comment: This was word-for-word what I was going to write. :-(